# What sort of sugar to add to coffee?

Tags: flavor, sugar

Sometimes I like to add a bit of sugar to my coffee. Does it matter what sort of sugar I use?

Will the type of sugar make any difference to the taste? Does it depend on the type of coffee?

White sugar or brown sugar? Demerara sugar seems to be a popular option for coffee. Or some sort of raw or unrefined sugar?

Does the crystal size make a difference?

Comment: Personally I like organic raw sugar much better than regular white sugar. I don't like brown sugars in coffee. One thing you might want to try is honey.

Comment: Not that it matters to the taste but I like the sugar cubes. There's a tactile pleasure (even if using tongs) in placing the cubes into the coffee. (usually for me it would be expresso.)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it makes a difference to the taste. As for what to pick - what you like.

My favorite is "Vermont Coffee" - ie, use maple syrup (or sugar, but syrup is more cost-effective, at least near a production area where the cost is not much shipping.)

Friends in the UK introduced me to Demerara, which is a not-quite fully refined sugar with a delicate carmel taste. Some of the "raw sugar" products sold in the USA approximate this, and some better than others.

At times I use USA brown sugar, which is basically white sugar sprayed with molasses, and not nearly as delicately flavored as a result.

Plain old white sugar is what it is, and if that's what you want, that's fine too.

I certainly have no difficulty distinguishing all of these from each other, in coffee - your taste buds/nose may vary.

Grain size affects only speed and ease of dissolving. Particularly in summer I tend to keep a bottle of **2 sugar:1 water simple syrup** in the fridge for easily mixed, pre-dissolved sugar (not just for coffee.)

Answer (score 3):

Sugar is pretty much sugar...
They will all add about the same intensity of "sweetness" to your cup.

http://foodwatch.com.au/blog/carbs-sugars-and-fibres/item/7-types-of-sugar-which-is-healthier.html

Your "brown or naturals" will add a bit of more flavor than regular "white" but it might get lost by stronger flavor of your cup of coffee. Can't hurt to try though.

As far as grain size. The smaller the grain the faster and easier it will dissolve.

Answer (score 3):

Over the years I've tried a number of sweeteners in my coffee. Everything from white, brown, turbinado, raw, stevia and truvia. I've even discovered an organic, gluten free, kosher [flavored coffee syrup brand](http://www.naturesflavors.com/) that gives me the option of having a bit of fun with my coffee.

It is true that [sugar is sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sugar) no matter what the form and it will convert the same way in your body. As for taste, I find that white leaves too much of an artificial taste and I defintiley don't have a liking for stevia or truvia.  The aftertaste it too much for me.

I do have to say though that my favorite sweetener for coffee is sweetened condensed milk.  I am more of an [Vietnamese iced coffee](http://www.chestbrew.com/single-post/2016/05/02/C%C3%A0-ph%C3%AA-s%E1%BB%AFa-%C4%91%C3%A1-its-whats-up-in-your-cup) fan as opposed to hot brews but I've also added the condensed milk to my traditional drip coffee and it gives it this creamy, smooth texture that I love. Another bonus is that it acts as both a milk and sugar so that's one less step I have to take.  Perfect for those busy mornings.